# Get the count of active employees in a given quarter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I need to come up with a query for the usecase mentioned here.

****Employee_Table****

1. Status is inactive if the employee no longer exists in current (latest) quarter
2. Updated (qtr) value is insert as part of data upload
3. Created value is  added when the row is inserted for the first time.

```
Emp_Name    id  created  updated  status
a            1  Q1FY20   Q1FY21   ACTIVE
b            2  Q1FY20   Q1FY21   ACTIVE
c            3  Q2FY20   Q4FY20   INACTIVE
d            4  Q2FY20   Q3FY20   INACTIVE
e            5  Q1FY21   Q1FY21   ACTIVE
```

**Quarter_list_table**

```
Id (randomly generated incremental)                qtr

1                                                  Q1FY20
2                                                  Q2FY20
3                                                  Q3FY20
4                                                  Q4FY20
5                                                  Q1FY21
```

**Details**

1. New quarter is inserted in Quarter_list_table when new quarter data is uploaded in the above Employee_Table
2. Id is generated randomly but in a incremental way. So at any point of time the latest qtr will have the highest id value.

Now I need to get a count of active employees in every quarter and show it in a bar chart. I just know each employee should be counted as  existing in all the quarters between and including  the created and updated qtr values. However I am not able to come up with the sql to get the count of the employee active in each qtr.

Comment: What's the purpose of the QUARTER_LIST table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view for the `Quarter_List_Table` then it will be in-sync with the `Employees` table.

```sql
CREATE VIEW Quarter_list_table ( id, qtr ) AS
SELECT ROWNUM,
       qtr
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         qtr
  FROM   employees
  UNPIVOT ( qtr FOR type IN ( created, updated ) )
  ORDER BY SUBSTR( qtr, -2 ), SUBSTR( qtr, 2, 1 )
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( Emp_Name, id, created, updated, status ) AS
SELECT 'a', 1, 'Q1FY20', 'Q1FY21', 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2, 'Q1FY20', 'Q1FY21', 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 3, 'Q2FY20', 'Q4FY20', 'INACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 4, 'Q2FY20', 'Q3FY20', 'INACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'e', 5, 'Q1FY21', 'Q1FY21', 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL;
```

Means the view contains:

> ```
> ID | QTR   
> -: | :-----
>  1 | Q1FY20
>  2 | Q2FY20
>  3 | Q3FY20
>  4 | Q4FY20
>  5 | Q1FY21
> ```

Then you can join the two tables together and aggregate to get your counts (which would be much easier if your quarters were written as `FY20Q1` then you could just use an alpha-numeric comparison ... but we can swap it round to make use of that):

```sql
SELECT MAX(q.qtr) AS qtr,
       COUNT( DISTINCT e.id ) AS cnt
FROM   Quarter_List_Table q
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e 
       ON ( SUBSTR( q.qtr, 3 ) || SUBSTR( q.qtr, 1, 2 )
              BETWEEN SUBSTR( e.created, 3 ) || SUBSTR( e.created, 1, 2 )
              AND     SUBSTR( e.updated, 3 ) || SUBSTR( e.updated, 1, 2 )
            AND e.status = 'ACTIVE'
          )
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.id
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> QTR    | CNT
> :----- | --:
> Q1FY20 |   2
> Q2FY20 |   2
> Q3FY20 |   2
> Q4FY20 |   2
> Q1FY21 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10fbf0fbfb1693d632cb7407b3c19f81)*

---

Or, you may want to use a row generator to create all the quarters between the minimum and the maximum:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Quarter_list_table ( id, qtr ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS( min_qtr, 3 * LEVEL - 3 ),
         '"Q"Q"FY"YY'
       )
FROM   (
  SELECT MIN(
           ADD_MONTHS(
             DATE '1999-10-01',
             3 * SUBSTR( qtr, 2, 1 ) + SUBSTR( qtr, -2 ) * 12 
           )
         ) AS min_qtr,
         MAX(
           ADD_MONTHS(
             DATE '1999-10-01',
             3 * SUBSTR( qtr, 2, 1 ) + SUBSTR( qtr, -2 ) * 12 
           )
         ) AS max_qtr
  FROM   employees
  UNPIVOT ( qtr FOR type IN ( created, updated ) )
)
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( min_qtr, level * 3 - 3 ) <= max_qtr;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=62993fc71dee420cc9b361b7a107618a)*